# How to convert the time zone of the values of a Pandas Series

Tags: datetime, numpy, timezone, pandas

I have a pandas Series with values of type `datetime64[ns]`. The dates are in EST timezone, and I would like to convert them to UTC timezone.

E.g.,

```
 s=pd.Series(pd.date_range('2012-1-1 1:30',periods=3,freq='min'))
```

How to convert `s` to UTC?

(Note that I don't actually use `date_range()` so using its `tz` parameter is not an option.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Update: In recent pandas, you can use the dt accessor to broadcast this:

```
In [11]: s.dt.tz_localize('UTC')
Out[11]:
0   2012-01-01 01:30:00+00:00
1   2012-01-01 01:31:00+00:00
2   2012-01-01 01:32:00+00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

---

Here's one way (depending  if tz is already set it might be a [`tz_convert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tz_convert.html#pandas.Series.tz_convert) rather than [`tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html#pandas.Series.tz_localize)):

```
In [21]: from pandas.lib import Timestamp

In [22]: s.apply(lambda x: x.tz_localize('UTC')) 
Out[22]: 
0    2012-01-01 06:30:00+00:00
1    2012-01-01 06:31:00+00:00
2    2012-01-01 06:32:00+00:00
```

Comment: This works, but it's really slow. Is there no broadcast-based way to do this?

Comment: Yes! Use `s.dt.tz_localize` (this wasn't available in 2012 :) )

Comment: could you post that as a new answer so I can up-vote it?

Comment: @ChrisWithers I edited it to my old answer (I don't think it's different enough for a new one - it's the same method really) but thanks for the upvote thought! :)