# How to convert a column in the pandas dataframe from UTC to datetime64?

Tags: pandas, date, datetime

I have a column in a dataframe which is currently a string:
'4/17/2015 8:03:45 PM'
I need to create other columns based on this column 
['dayofweek','dayofmonth']

I couldnt find a fast solution which could help me do that for 60 000 000 rows, pls help )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert the time zone of the values of a Pandas Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004545/how-to-convert-the-time-zone-of-the-values-of-a-pandas-series)

Comment: A simliar question has already been asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004545/how-to-convert-the-time-zone-of-the-values-of-a-pandas-series. There are other similar questions you can also look at. Then, you can just map over your rows and apply one of the available solutions. Please try to search the site before posting questions.

Answer (score 0):

## You can create a function(s) to convert the date in your dataframe to the output you need and than add the result as a new columns in your dataframe as below:

```
df

    numbers time
0   1       2019-01-01
1   2       2019-01-02
2   3       2019-01-03
3   4       2019-01-04
4   5       2019-01-05
5   6       2019-01-06
6   7       2019-01-07
7   8       2019-01-08
8   9       2019-01-09
9   10      2019-01-10
10  11      2019-01-11
11  12      2019-01-12
```

## Create the function to apply to your data columns to your dataframe

```
def day_of_the_week(value):
    return value.strftime("%A")

def day_of_the_month(value):
    return value.day
```

## Create the new columns by applying the functions to the dataframe date columns

```
df['day_of_the_week'] = df['time'].apply(day_of_the_week)
df['day_of_the_month'] = df['time'].apply(day_of_the_month)
```

## Get the update Datafame

```
df
    numbers time        day_of_the_week day_of_the_month
0   1       2019-01-01  Tuesday         1
1   2       2019-01-02  Wednesday       2
2   3       2019-01-03  Thursday        3
3   4       2019-01-04  Friday          4
4   5       2019-01-05  Saturday        5
5   6       2019-01-06  Sunday          6
6   7       2019-01-07  Monday          7
7   8       2019-01-08  Tuesday         8
8   9       2019-01-09  Wednesday       9
9   10      2019-01-10  Thursday        10
10  11      2019-01-11  Friday          11
11  12      2019-01-12  Saturday        12
```

Comment: THANKS! Just curious: is it possible to do the same thing placing the original function instead of creating a function or there s no use of it?